# Retrieve value of lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda, expression

I have this function:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> exp1, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> exp2, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> exp3)
    {


    }
```

and i use the function like this :

```
adverts.WhereIf(x=>x.DeactivatedDate.HasValue, x => x.DeactivatedDate.Value > starDateTime, x => x.ModifiedDate > starDateTime);
```

How can i get the value of exp1 ?

Comment: This function does not make any sense to me. I see no difference from  `Where(x => ... ? ... : ...)`

Comment: I don't understand - `exp1` is an expression that you passed to `Whereif`, so it's "value" is `x=>x.DeactivatedDate.HasValue`.  Do you mean you want to _evaluate_ that expression against some object and see what value it returns?

Comment: The problem is i need to use if condition somehow in where() clause . because of that i create a this extension , if u have a suggestion , i will be so thankful to know .

Comment: i want to get the value of DeactivatedDate.HasValue  in that extension .

Comment: In the extenssion i need to know if DeactivatedDate.HasValue is true , do something  .

Comment: @DStanley  In the extension i am gonna say  if ( x=>x.DeactivatedDate.HasValue == true )  return (x => x.DeactivatedDate.Value > starDateTime ) otherwise return (x => x.ModifiedDate > starDateTime)

Comment: That will return an _Expression_.  You want to return an `IQueryable`.  I would suggest asking that as a different question.

Answer (score 1):

> In the extenssion i need to know if DeactivatedDate.HasValue is true

You can evaluate the expression, but you need an instance of `TSource` to evaluate against.  Since your "input" is a collection of `TSource` youe solution might be something like:

```
foreach(TSource t in source)
{
    bool isTrue = exp1.Compile()(t);  //  evaluate exp1 for this item
    if(isTrue)
        // do something
    else
        // do something else
}
```

but note that your return type in an `IQueryable<TSource>` - so I'm not sure you've fully thought through how you intend to build up the resulting query...

Comment: in this line i have problem   bool isTrue = exp1(t);  
it does not accept exp1(t);

Comment: Now it works . As u can see my extension has an output (  IQueryable<TSource>)  how can i  apply my condition on source and send it back as IQueryable<TSource> ?